# Display value of radio button

Tags: php, javascript

How can I get the `$ObjName` to not equal the value of the last object looped but the selected radio button. It will change inside the showit text field but it will still give me the value of the end of the look. I want `$ObjIndex` to equal whats inside the text field.

#### JavaScript Code

```
<script>
function gtdoc()
{
    var itog = document.myform.tog;
    for(var i=0; i < document.myform.tog.length; i++)
    {
        if(document.myform.tog[i].checked)
        { 
            var iitog = document.myform.tog[i].value;
            document.myform.showit.value = iitog;
            document.getElementById("HiddenDoc2").style.display = 'block';
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

#### PHP Code

```
while( $row1 = mysql_fetch_array($myQ1) ) 
{  
    echo "<td><input type='radio' name='tog[]' id='tog' onClick='gtdoc();'value='$row1[2]'>$row1[3]</input></td></tr>"; 
}
echo "<input type='text' name='showit' id='showit' value=''></input>";
$ObjName = $_POST['showit'];
```

Comment: I am unsure how this is not working for you.

Comment: Seriously, what is the problem?

Comment: $ObjName will only give me the last looped value but the textbox showit will give me the selected radio value inside the text box. How do I get them to match? Its all on one page and my form action is posting to itself <form name="myform" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST">

Comment: Do you call gtdoc() on submit input? Can you add in your question all the HTML code?

Answer (score 0):

Change `name='tog[]'` to `name='tog[aMeaningfulIndex]'`, then you can access `$_POST['tog']['aMeaningfulIndex']`